# How to use only one RequireJS config file for different path js file?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

I am integrating RequireJS into my project. My project structure like below:

```
$ tree
.
|-- common.js
|-- lib
|   |-- jquery.min.js
|   `-- require.js
`-- view
    |-- a
    |   |-- a.html
    |   |-- a.js
    |   `-- b
    |       |-- b.html
    |       `-- b.js
    |-- c.html   
    `-- c.js
```

**common.js** is my RequireJS config file, content like below:

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: '../lib',
    paths: {
        'jquery': 'jquery.min'
    }
});
```

There are js files in different path in **/view**.

**c.js** running well as below:

```
requirejs(['../common'], function (common) {
    requirejs(['jquery'], function($){
    .......
    });
});
```

But how can I inject **'jquery'** in **a.js** or **b.js** and still use **common.js**?

Comment: Did you forget to change the path to `common.js`? It should of course be `requirejs(['../../common'], function (common) { ... });` from `a.js` and `requirejs(['../../../common'], function (common) { ... });` from `b.js`, since paths are relative to the current file.

Comment: I changed, but jquery path must be changed too, I do not want change it, and I want to use **'jquery'** for a.js, b.js and c.js. Just like AngularJS injection.

Comment: No, you shouldn't need to change the path for jquery. It finds the jquery path by looking in `common.js`. But finding `common.js` itself is done differently: you've done it as a path relative to the file which is searching for it (`'../common'` from `c.js`). Alternatively, you could use an absolute path: `'/common'`. That's assuming `common.js` is at the root of the directory tree in the URL, e.g. `http://example.com/common.js` and not `http://example.com/scripts/common.js`, in which case you could use `/scripts/common.js`.

Comment: Thank you for your remind, I've changed relative path to absolute path.

Comment: And did that fix it?

Comment: Yes, and I accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget to change the path to common.js. It should be:

```
requirejs(['../../common'], function (common) { ... });
```

from a.js and

```
requirejs(['../../../common'], function (common) { ... });
```

from b.js, since paths are relative to the current file.

Alternatively, use an absolute path. That way the path is the same no matter which file you're `requirejs`ing from. For example, if `common.js` is at http://www.example.com/scripts/common.js, use

```
requirejs(['/common'], function (common) { ... });
```

. (The leading `/` makes it an absolute path.)